# how to use the dynamic PHP ajax data with the bootpag

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

How can I display the dynamic content of PHP with bootstrap pagination.The result is displaying using ajax call in div id 'msrResult', how to use that div in  bootstrap pagination code. Here my code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//raw.github.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master /lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<div id="content2">Dynamic Content goes here</div>
<div id="page-selection">Pagination goes here</div>
<script>
$('#page-selection').bootpag({
total: 23,
page: 1,
maxVisible: 10
}).on('page', function(event, num){
$("#content2").html("Page " + num); // or some ajax content loading...
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

<div id=msrResult></div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation how to put the PHP content in "pages" (divs) or how to use the Bootstrap "pagination" component?

Comment: Yes, getResult.php is my ajax page, that contain data to be display in pagination, currently that is displayed in <div id=msrResult></div>,  I want to display using bootstrap pagination.

Comment: Please tell me where to use the ajax result in above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the "space" in the GitHub URL could produce 404 responses. You should delete it to get the script working ;)

Basically (as you can see at the authors website) clicking the page-buttons (they are showing up in `#page-selection` once the script is initialized correctly) triggers bootpag to toggle the content. In the `.on()` function you have the chance to place new content right before it shows up again.

In the script you've provided you write "Page X" in `#content2` before it shows up. But in your case you want to load dynamic content in this div so you could do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "source.php?site="+num
}).done(function(data) {
  $( "#content2" ).html( data );
});
```

in the `.on()` function to load the dynamic php content in your `#content2` div

Also see this JS fiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/628zL/3/

Comment: Hi I have used following code, but same data is reloading.:

Comment: You ` source.php ` file needs to have different outputs depending on `?site=XXX` in order to get different data on your page.

Comment: .on('page', function(event, num)
          {
           $("#msrResult").html("Page " + num); // or some ajax content loading...
          $.ajax({
           url: 'getResult.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
             formName:'afscpMsr',
             action:'search',
             field_nm: document.getElementById('msrdet').value,
             field_value:document.getElementById('srhmsr').value 
            }
           }).done(function(result_data){
  var v = document.getElementById("msrResult");
               v.innerHTML = result_data;
           });        
        });

Comment: Can't spot mistakes right know. What is the output? Do you see the output of "getResult.php" even once?

Comment: In the above code how to get the dynamic value of 'total'  attribute in boot-tag.

Comment: @ Daniel ,How give the dynamic value for 'total' in boot-pag pagination?

Comment: Try to load the amount of pages available with AJAX and put it in a variable. You can simply use variables as option in the initialization: `total: myvar,`

Comment: hi, is there any way of using that with CDN.

Answer (score 0):

U can easily do that by this way-

```js
$('#show_paginator').bootpag({
      total: 23,
      page: 3,
      maxVisible: 10
}).on('page', function(event, num)
{
     $("#dynamic_content").html("Page " + num); // or some ajax content loading...
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/jquery.bootpag.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="dynamic_content">Pagination goes here</div>
<div id="show_paginator"></div>
```

---

If u like to use customised version, then u can try this-

```js
$('#show_paginator').bootpag({
       total: 53,
       page: 2,
       maxVisible: 5,
       leaps: true,
       firstLastUse: true,
       first: '←',
       last: '→',
       wrapClass: 'pagination',
       activeClass: 'active',
       disabledClass: 'disabled',
       nextClass: 'next',
       prevClass: 'prev',
       lastClass: 'last',
       firstClass: 'first'
}).on('page', function(event, num)
{
     $("#dynamic_content").html("Page " + num); // or some ajax content loading...
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/jquery.bootpag.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="dynamic_content">Pagination goes here</div>
<div id="show_paginator"></div>
```

---

If u like to use more customization, u can try this **options**-

[image]

---

### Warning

Here I am using a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/jquery.bootpag.js) for showing content. But it is not recommanded.

Hardly recommendation is to download **[this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js)** and put it locally.

Because there is no official CDN for bootpeg.

---

Even more can be found [**from here**](http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#.VyRB1_kdAV8).

---

---

I think u have your complete answer.

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates.

Comment: Call ur AJAX in the JS code - "// or some ajax content loading..."

Comment: $("#dynamic_content").html("Page " + num);